# Quorum permissioned network

Tags: network

How can I permission a quorum network?
Imagine I have 3 nodes in my network and I install another node in my friends house.

How can I prevent my friend add more nodes to my quorum network?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I kindly suggest you to first go through the all official docs of Quorum permissioned network. you will definitely get all the answers you want to know.

And for your questions :

> How can I permission a quorum network? Imagine I have 3 nodes in my
>   network and I install another node in my friend's house.
>
> How can I prevent my friend to add more nodes to my quorum network?

I will recommend this link where you will find your answers. here that links :

1. [Quorum permissioned network](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Using-Quorum)
2. [Product Roadmap](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Product-Roadmap)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63881/decentralized-access-control-in-permissioned-blockchain) more than a year ago, and from what I have learned so far is: there is no easy answer to this.

You might have some of the following goals when running a permissioned network:
- Guarantee privacy withing your consortium / permissioned network by controlling who can read the chain
- Prohibit unauthorized nodes to send transactions or interact in any other way with the network

Achieving this probably depends on the consensus (who authored a block) and the system's overall design including governance.

Because it is questionable what happens if one node gets compromised and propagates tampered blocks or transactions or spams the network. What if a node in that list connects to nodes, that should not be part of the network?

Also there should be a mechanism in place that can add new nodes or blacklist some, preferably in a manner without introducing a SPOF.